# Php timestamp formatting not working

Tags: php

I am trying format a timestamp `Sat Sep 02 2017 06:00:00 GMT+0600 (Central Asia Standard Time)` into Y-m-d format.But this is not working i am getting 1970-01-01  as output.

My code:

```
   $date="Sat Sep 02 2017 06:00:00 GMT+0600 (Central Asia Standard Time)";

   $date_exist=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
    echo $date_exist;
```

Comment: This will work in this way
<?php

$date = "01-01-2017 23:23:59";

echo date('Y_m_d_His',strtotime($date));

?>

Comment: for my case how to format ?

Comment: Use date_parse()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code.

```
<?php

$date="Sat Sep 02 2017 06:00:00 GMT+0600 (Central Asia Standard Time)";
$dt  = date_parse ($date);

$dt_ = $dt['year'].'-'.$dt['month'].'-'.$dt['day'];


echo $date_exist=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dt_)); ?>
```

Comment: simply the perfect answer!can you tell why my code was working in local server ?

Comment: Let me give you a demo link for this code.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f5394f509122f2829d996f8b327de47c7ed9632f

Answer (score 0):

use [date_parse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php), with mktime() if you want to make a UNIX timestamp

```
$date="Sat Sep 02 2017 06:00:00 GMT+0600 (Central Asia Standard Time)";
$date_array= date_parse ($date);
echo mktime($date_array['hour'],$date_array['minute'],$date_array['second'],$date_array['day'],$date_array['month'],$date_array['year']);
```

Here is the output :

> 1486616400